# docker-compose --x-networking up not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up docker-compose network but command

```
docker-compose --x-networking up
```

Return standart docker-compose help output

```
Define and run multi-container applications with Docker.

Usage:
  docker-compose [-f=<arg>...] [options] [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
  docker-compose -h|--help

Options:
  -f, --file FILE           Specify an alternate compose file (default: docker-compose.yml)
  -p, --project-name NAME   Specify an alternate project name (default: directory name)
  --verbose                 Show more output
  -v, --version             Print version and exit

Commands:
  build              Build or rebui...
  (etc)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This depends on the version of docker-compose you're using. Versions before 1.5 did not have this flag. If you're using 1.6; the `--x-networking` flag is no longer present in 1.6 because it's now automatically used if your `docker-compose.yml` uses the 2.0 format

See the [release notes](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.6.0-rc1);

> Support for networking has exited experimental status and is the
>   recommended way to enable communication between containers.
>
> If you use the new file format, your app will use networking. If you
>   want to keep using links, just leave your Compose file as it is and
>   it'll continue to work just the same.
>
> By default, you don't have to configure any networks. In fact, using
>   networking with Compose involves even less configuration than using
>   links. Consult the networking guide for how to use it:
>   https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/1.6.0-rc1/docs/networking.md
>
> The experimental flags --x-networking and --x-network-driver,
>   introduced in Compose 1.5, have been removed.

Comment: So if i have docker-compose file like this
http://pastebin.com/NKugCHWk
How i can connect nginx with django for example after removing links? because i can not get it work.

nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "myapp-web" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp:16

sites-enabled/myapp file:
http://pastebin.com/u5BMSdVS

Comment: You do need docker 1.10 (currently available as release-candidate) for that to work properly. Docker 1.9 supported the new networking, but no option to add aliases for a container. In 1.9, you should be able to connect through the *container name* (e.g. `myproject_web_1`)

Comment: I upgraded my docker to 1.10 and it's still not working

Comment: Are you using the 2.0 format for your `docker-compose.yml` ? (Note that the `--x-networking...` flag should no longer be used in docker-compose 1.6

Comment: Ok. i got this. I had to change my docker-compose file to V2. THX